# What to do if a new package uses a command I already use as a personal macro?

Tags: macros, incompatibility, chemformula, backward-compatibility

In my documents, I use `\ch` as a shorthand for "ch." or "chap." or "chapter" (depending on the desired output style), as in `see \ch 3` (output: "see ch. 3" or "see chap. 3" or "see chapter 3"). I would now like to use `chemformula` in one of my documents. The trouble is that `chemformula`'s main command is also called `\ch`.

Is there any way to insert some code in the preamble that would let me use `\chem` (or some other such new command) for `chemformula` and continue using `\ch` for my own personal macro?

To be clear, I would like a solution that does not involve changing all of my documents where I use `\ch`.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

% This package defines `\ch`:
%\usepackage{chemformula}

% My personal macro also defines `\ch`:
\usepackage{biblatex} % defines `\unspace`
\newcommand\ch{ch.\unspace~}

\begin{document}

See \ch 3.

Iron sulfate (\ch{FeSO4}).

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not related to the actual question itself, but why not use a package like `cleveref` instead of using `See \ch 3.`? With `cleveref`, you can determine how the word "chapter" is is used in the reference and the corresponding number also updates automatically if you decide to move chapters around later.

Comment: I didn't know about `cleveref`. It looks like a useful package. As far as I can tell, though, it is only useful for cross references within a document, not for citing another book's chapters. Isn't that right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\let\chemformula\ch` and then redefine `\ch`

```
\documentclass{article}
% This package defines `\ch`:
\usepackage{chemformula}
% This copies the definition of \ch to \chemformula
\let\chemformula\ch
% You can now redefine \ch
% My personal macro also defines `\ch`:
\usepackage{biblatex} % defines `\unspace`
\renewcommand\ch{ch.\unspace~}

\begin{document}

See \ch 3.

Iron sulfate (\chemformula{FeSO4}).

\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** You shouldn't recur to maniputating TeX primitives often, unless you're really sure of what are you doing. That being said, smoke'em if you got'em